# How to hide and reveal text on click after certain length in Angular10?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a long text. I am trying to add a "Show more" and "Show Less" button to reveal and hide the text after certain length with a animation.
I know how to display and hide a certain text on a click. But, it doesn't look great.
I have also tried with CSS: `overflow` property. But, it just hides the text.

I want to hide the text in html after 15 characters and display the button. When I click on the button, it should expand and show me the remaining and button content should be changed to "Show less"

```js
function func(){
    alert("hi");
}
```

```css
a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="more">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis,
    quam ligula sodales orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus.
    Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris
    blandit id luctus felis convallis.
    Integer varius egestas vestibulum.
    Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.
</div>

<a onClick="func()">Show more</a>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail to your problem. Are you looking for general purpose, or a solution that is specific to your structure.

Comment: I want the to hide and display the text after 15 character length on clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can deliver a part of the solution. Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jngvgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

The only problem is, that the css properties `overflow` and `text-overflow` cannot be animated, so you wouldn't have a smooth transition... For that you could either create a specific animation or use a different css approach like changing the height or using opacity and a transition delay. Also to check the length of the content you would need more logic, which I didn't include in this solution, since I don't think it would be necessary because you could limit the width of the element and therefore cut the text.

Answer (score 1):

### Insert Hide/Reveal 'Panel' Component via Directive

In this approach we adopt a strategy for attaching a directive to an arbitrary block-level element containing a single textNode as a direct descendent, with the goal of wrapping this textNode in a component which can truncate its length with reveal/hide features.

**The solution will require**

- 1 Directive
- 1 Component

**Why this approach**

- We do not wish to concern ourselves with the hide/show logic state in each component which has to implement this behaviour, so it is better if we can componentize and make it deal directly with its own state
- We want to be able to easily change the look/feel of the show/hide feature across all usages.
- we can apply any animations needed via the Angular Animations states on the component itself.

#### The Component

We will first create our component, because our Directive depends on it in order to be able to create it.

**controller**

```js
export class TruncateWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
  private _longText!: string
  private _shortText!: string;
  showLess = true;

  constructor(private change: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  setTruncateContent(truncateLength: number, textNode: Node) {
    this._longText = textNode.textContent ?? "";
    this._shortText = this._longText.slice(0, truncateLength);
    this.change.detectChanges();
  }

  get short() {
    return this._shortText
  }

  get long() {
    return this._longText;
  }
  
}
```

**notice:** we have to import a ChangeDetectorRef because we will be setting the longText and shortText private properties directly from our directive outside of the Angular ChangeDetection cycle.

**Template**

```html
<div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="showLess; else more">
    <div>
      {{short}}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button (click)="showLess = !showLess">Show more</button>
    </div>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-template #more>
      <div>
        {{long}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button (click)="showLess = !showLess">Show Less</button>
      </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

#### The Directive

Now that we have a component, let us create a directive which we can utilize within our other templates to insert the component.

```js
@Directive({selector: '[truncate]'})
export class TruncateDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() truncate: number = 15;
  textNode!: Node;
  private readonly componentFactory: ComponentFactory<TruncateWrapperComponent>;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
              private render: Renderer2,
              private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
              factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    // prime a component factory for creating the wrapper component.
    this.componentFactory = factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TruncateWrapperComponent)
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.shouldProcess()) {
      this.createWrapper();
    }
  }

  /**
   * shouldProcess checks the nativeElement which the directive is attached to for any direct descendent textNodes. The
   * first textNode encountered will be inserted into the TruncateWrapperComponent. Any original content other than
   * the first textNode encountered will be removed when the wrapper is created.
   *
   * If no direct textNode descendants are found no wrapper will be created and the original content will remain.
   */
  shouldProcess() {
    // check for textNodes, which is nodeType 3.
    const children = this.element.nativeElement.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (children[i].nodeType == 3) {
        this.textNode = children[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    return Boolean(this.textNode);
  }

  createWrapper() {
    // clear current content
    this.render.setProperty(this.element.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', '');
    // attach new component to view.
    const wrapText = this.viewContainer.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
    wrapText.instance.setTruncateContent(this.truncate, this.textNode);
  }
}
```

#### StackBlitz

[Here is a StackBlitz demonstrating the implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ihvra1?file=src/app/directives/truncate.directive.ts)